# How to model relationship between multiple many to many object

Tags: c#, many-to-many, domain-driven-design, relationship

I am working on an old c# application which uses iBatis as ORM. I have some problem modelling two new entities I have to add to my domain.

I have 3 old entities involved: `Process`, `Society` and `Activity`

and now I have to add:

- a many to many relationship between process and society
- a many to many relationship between activity and the M2M relationship aforementioned

both relationship have some properties and i have to access them from both directions:
I need to know:

- all process of a society
- all society involved in a process
- all activity done on a process of a society
- all process of all society analyzed in an activity

as all others M2M in my project I mapped the first relationship as 3 object:

- `BaseLinkProcessSociety`  which contains relationship properties (process relevance for society and person in charge)
- `LinkProcessSociety` which extend base object with the addition of Society object
- `LinkSocietyProcess` which extend base object with the addition of Process object

in this way in my `Process` object I have list of `LinkProcessSociety` while in `Society` object i have list of `LinkSocietyProcess` object

Now the question is: how can I map the second M2M relationship? I don't have an object that map the entire ProcessSociety. Do I have to create it? I don't like the idea very much

Are there any other better modelling solutions?

**EDIT for @Sebastian Oliveri answer**

in M2M object i have to add some property, so it can't be generic,

using your `ProcessOfSociety` object:

```
class ProcessOfSociety {
    var processId;
    var societyId;
    Person personInCharge;
    int relevance;
}
```

but my problem is: how do you map this object as property in `Process` object?

i would like to have something like this

```
class Process {
    var processId;
    var processDescription;
    IList<ProcessOfSociety> SocietyInvolvedList; 
}
```

with this protocol:

```
process.SocietyInvolvedList[1].Society.societyDescription
```

and even

```
class Society{
    var societyId;
    var societyDescription;
    IList<ProcessOfSociety> FolowedProcesses; 
}
```

with this protocol:

```
society.FolowedProcesses[1].Process.processDescription
```

so i can't have only id properties in `ProcessOfSociety`

Answer (score 0):

In these kind of scenarios you need to forget about thinking in the classic relational approach and to make the relationship as a first class concept.
In order to create a relationship as a first class concept you first need created one of those two objects that are going to be related to each other. In this case you need a Society so somewhere in your application you will have:

```
society = new Society("my society");
societyRepository.add(society);
```

In some other place in your application you will have the "service" the will create a process related to a society:

```
society = societyRepository.get(societyId);
process = processRepository.get(processId);
processOfSociety = society.register(process);
processesOfSocietyRepository.add(processOfSociety);
```

The ProcessOfSociety class models the relationship between a society and a process.

```
class ProcessOfSociety {

    var processId;
    var societyId;

    ...

}
```

Of course you need a Process to be related. Process is an aggregate on its own being Process the AR so the precondition to model the above steps is to have a process created first.

You need to do the same for the Activity Aggregate following the same concepts I described above. Remember that these classes that play the roles of relationships holds the identifiers of aggregates and not the aggregates promoting the disconnected model.

Pay attention that the ProcessOfSociety class models the relationship. You need to think what the protocol of those objects would be. If it is just getProcessId() and getSocietyId() and that's all then you could think about a better abstraction that can be reused for other uses cases. If you JUST want to model the relationship between two objects as many to many then the response to this answer is in the title you wrote for this post:

```
class ManyToManyRelationship {

    var left;
    var right;

}
```

Many many times In DDD (OOP) the answer is in the domain semantics :)

UPDATE to answer you question:

You do not need the Society to hold a list of ProcessOfSociety. Both are aggregates with global identity so they have their own repositories so if you want to find all the processes of a Society you will need to use the repository:

```
List processesOfSociety = processesOfSocietyRepository.find(societyId)
```

Remember that aggregates are in general a "tiny" aggrupation of value objects, they might have a list of value objects inside its boundary but if you make an aggregate hold a reference to another aggregate then that's a smell design. In your scenario you make an aggregate hold a list of other aggregates.

Hope it helps.